# Output to 3.5mm female jack from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, audio

Can anybody point me toward some resources about using a microcontroller to output to a 3.5mm female jack (the kind that you plug headphones into)? I can't seem to find any explanation of what sort of signal is necessary, or just how to make this happen in general.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the microcontroller generating that should be sent to an audio jack?

Comment: Ideally, the microcontroller will be sending whatever sort of signal is needed to drive a 3.5mm jack. Essentially, I'm building an electronic drum machine, with the microcontroller acting as the synthesizer, that needs to output to a 3.5mm jack.

Comment: Two options then: I2S to a codec chip, or PWM audio to an amp.

Comment: 3.5mm jack is a mechanical interface. What electrical signal you will transmit through it is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want stereo audio output, you can have the MCU talk to a codec chip using something like I2S, and have the codec produce analog signals that can feed the output amplifier.

There are one-chip solutions for this kind of thing, for example, [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv320aic3268.pdf) TI part which contains a modest headphone output amplifier as well as mini-DSP functions. There are simpler chips such as [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv320aic3253.pdf) one.

Answer (score -1):

pretty easy. Set the R divider to get the volume you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVoMj3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Well you can do much better than this (PWM, DACs, etc etc). But this is the starting point to drive your headphones.

Comment: The OP did not ask for a volume control circuit...